# How often does accelerometer method update?

Tags: iphone, ipad, cocos2d-iphone

I'm testing the response time differences between the native `accelerometer` method and the cocos2d `udpate` method (which is every frame, or 60 times a second if using the maximum frame rate) where `update` takes variable information that is updated in `accelerometer`.

Of course, when moving sprites across the screen using just the accelerometer method, they are not smooth and even if the sprite's position is calculated the same with the `acceleration` response in either `accelerometer` and `update` the accelerometer method clearly doesn't update as often as the sprite moves much more slowly across the screen.

I'm guessing this is because iOS does not natively update the `UIAccelerometer` anywhere near 60 times a second, so does anyone know where I can find out how often it does?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

its up to you.
the `UIAccelerometer` object has `Updateinterval` property that you defined
how many times the accelerometer will update.
Ex:

```
UIAccelerometer *Accel;
Accel.updateInterval = 1.0f/30.0f;
```

which mean 30 times per one seconed.
it can take up to 60.